# Usage of sympy checksol - got some results that failed verification in Excel

Tags: excel, sympy

Thanks for reading:
I have some confusion when trying to solve a group of linear equations using sympy, where I encountered huge frustration in achieving consistent outcomes from different sympy and scipy solvers as well as against MathCAD. I must be missing something.  The following is a simple piece of the puzzle, please could someone help to point out my issue, thanks in advance!

```
#-------------------------------------
import sympy as sy 
#
def test_sols(f=None,sols_test=None):
    C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8=sy.symbols('C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8')
    #
    Cs=[C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8]
    #
    dct=dict(zip(Cs,sols_test))
    isRoot=sy.checksol(f,dct)
    print(isRoot)
    #
    err=f.evalf(subs=dct)
    print(err)
    #
#
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8=sy.symbols('C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8')
#
f=C1 + 0.5*C2 + 1033885634874.62*C3 + 1033885634874.62*C4 - C5 - 0.5*C6 - 1033885634874.62*C7 - 1033885634874.62*C8 - 0.0636904761904762
sols_test_1=[0.133112996062315,0,0,0,0.196961877236444,-0.254761904761905,163772637.090428,-163772637.090428]
sols_test_2=[0.133112996062315,0,0,0,0.196961877236444,-0.254761904761905,0,0]
#
test_sols(f,sols_test_1)
test_sols(f,sols_test_2) 
# -----------------------------------------------------
```

The above code attempts to test two sets of solutions to a multivariate (C1...C8) expression f.  The outcomes from the code are True and False for sols_test_1 and sols_test_2, respectively. [screenshot of bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWlrA.png)
I put the numbers into Excel but found opposite conclusion [Excel verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTodf.png) .  I obtained in Excel a value(error) of f(sol_test_1)= -0.063690476 and f(sol_test_2)= -0.000158405.  The former error is larger than the latter, suggesting a conclusion of False and True for sols_test_1 and sols_test_2, respectively.

I suspect I  have usage problem with regard to the sympy number types or alikes.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding and subtracting very large numbers with very small numbers. This is problematic in floating point due to catastrophic cancellation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation

Using sympy you can compute the results exactly with no rounding error:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import Rational as R

C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8 = syms = sy.symbols('C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8')

f = (C1 + R('0.5')*C2 + R('1033885634874.62')*C3 + R('1033885634874.62')*C4 - C5
    - R('0.5')*C6 - R('1033885634874.62')*C7 - R('1033885634874.62')*C8 -
    R('0.0636904761904762'))

sols_test_1=[R('0.133112996062315'),0,0,0,R('0.196961877236444'),
             R('-0.254761904761905'),R('163772637.090428'),R('-163772637.090428')]
sols_test_2=[R('0.133112996062315'),0,0,0,R('0.196961877236444'),R('-0.254761904761905'),0,0]

print(f.subs(zip(syms, sols_test_1)))
print(f.subs(zip(syms, sols_test_2)))
```

This gives:

```
-1584049836527/10000000000000000
-1584049836527/10000000000000000
```

So both answers give the same error if the calculation is performed exactly. The error here is small compared to some of the very large terms in the equation. In a floating point computation it's hard to say whether that should be considered a "solution" or not by `checksol`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
So actually my excel verification went wrong due to the catastrophic cancelation.  I also noticed that my code produced identical error to your "Rationalised" one, could it be due to they being converted to sumpy objects automatically?
My other takeaway is that the checksol is not suitable for this case of floating-point computation.

Comment: I would rather say that floating point is not suitable for this kind of task than checksol itself. As you can see it fails in excel and other environments as well. SymPy can compute in floating point with higher precision and high enough precision would resolve this. Unfortunately the numbers you gave as input in your code were Python float literals which must always have a precision of 53 bits so SymPy can't improve the accuracy if the inputs are given as floats like that.

Comment: Thanks again Oscar. Yes indeed, that makes sense.    I am wondering would the problem still exists if those float numbers were calculated internally via expr.subs() method, instead of direct input?  Since my code above was a simplified example where I copied the float numbers from the command line.    In my original code, it's more like: function f(x,y,C1...C8)  then clearing out x and y by doing  f.subs((x,x_float_input),(y,y_float_input))  where x_float_input and y_float_input are still float numbers but are "normal" short ones, such as 0.5, 2.54e3 or 300e9, alikes.

Comment: You would have the same problem with `subs`. The `evalf(subs=...)` method is provided that should be able to handle this sort of thing but it will only work in a case like this if the *input* you provide is eaxct.